# why jamendo is off stores of music player banshee and rhythmbox and how can i add jamendo to the stores?

Tags: ubuntu-one, banshee, rhythmbox

jamendo is open music platform for artists and listers, i know that debian was on jamendo on the stores on rhythmbox by default, and also ubuntu use to have

so why is not been there anymore on ubuntu ?
is it because of ubuntu one ?

and how can i add jamendo to the music players like rhythmbox and banshee ?

magnatune store is on rhytmbox plugins bu t not on banshee ?

can we expect jamendo to be include on next release , that i am using beta version, of ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 3):

Jamendo was removed from the upstream code, for Rhythmbox. Banshee does not ship a Magnatune store, as far as I know. To get Jamendo in Banshee, it looks like you can install the `banshee-extension-jamendo` package. I have not tried it though.

http://git.gnome.org/browse/rhythmbox/commit/?id=5db81f7c22d7d558663e2f6db3bdcb871d3d482f is the commit where Jamendo was removed from Rhythmbox. It looks like it wasn't technically feasible to keep around for now. I suspect because of the way Jamendo works as a store, it had to be implemented in a certain way, and that it isn't good from a technical/performance perspective, as it required downloading the entire catalog all the time. Its removal from Rhythmbox has nothing to do with Ubuntu One though. It was a purely upstream decision.